# Counting survival rate for male and females

Tags: r

I have this data set:

```
library(earth)
data(etitanic)
```

I made a variable that just stores the survival rate and the sex from the `etitanic` data:

```
Survival_MF <- etitanic[2:3]
```

Now I want to find the survival rate of male and females. I haven't used R in quite along time. In C++ I would simply write a for loop to count how many times we have a number 1(survived) given string is "male".

How would I accomplish this task in R? I tried using

```
prop.table(table(etitanic$sex, etitanic$survived))
```

and I get this:

```
                 0         1
  female 0.0917782 0.2791587
  male   0.5000000 0.1290631
```

Does that look correct?

Comment: `sum(Survival_MF[Survival_MF$sex == "male", 1])` does the trick.  Since the death value is 0 and this doesn't affect the column sum, you don't need to filter by whether they survived or not

Comment: @Punintended Thank you and how would we count how many males there are to get the survival rate, we have to divide sum(Survival_MF[Survival_MF$sex == "male", 1]) by number of males right?

Comment: That's correct.  Though my format is just a quick answer to your previous question.  neilfws' version is cleaner and more easily interpretable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it several ways - but none of them should involve a loop. I'd use `dplyr::count()`:

```
library(dplyr)
etitanic %>% 
  count(sex,survived)

  sex    survived     n
  <fct>     <int> <int>
1 female        0    96
2 female        1   292
3 male          0   523
4 male          1   135
```

You could group by sex to calculate proportions by sex:

```
etitanic %>% 
  count(sex,survived) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(rate = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup()

  sex    survived     n  rate
  <fct>     <int> <int> <dbl>
1 female        0    96 0.247
2 female        1   292 0.753
3 male          0   523 0.795
4 male          1   135 0.205
```

Or just omit the grouping for proportions of total persons.

If you want to "do stuff with data frames", it's well worth learning `dplyr`.

Comment: what about this: prop.table(table(etitanic$sex, etitanic$survived))?

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing but using the library(sqldf)?

Comment: See here if you want to answer another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553697/using-the-sqldf-library-from-r-to-write-a-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

Using `subset` to filter entries based on `sex == "male"` and `survived == 1`:

```
nrow(subset(etitanic, sex == "male" & survived == 1))
#[1] 135
```

Or as a fraction of total:

```
nrow(subset(etitanic, sex == "male" & survived == 1)) / nrow(etitanic)
#[1] 0.1290631
```

Comment: prop.table(table(etitanic$sex, etitanic$survived))

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Yes that gives you a table of the fractions for males/females that survived/died. Entry `[2,2]` is the same as "fraction of total" above.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing but using the library(sqldf)?

Comment: See here if you want to answer another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553697/using-the-sqldf-library-from-r-to-write-a-select-statement

Comment: Can you help me with the latter above link please?