# Using the sqldf library from R to write a SELECT statement

Tags: r, sqldf

I have the data:

```
library(earth)
data(etitanic)
```

I also need to use the library

```
library(sqldf)
```

My goal is to write a SELECT statement that returns the survival rates by gender. My statement must include the etitanic data frame (treated like a database table).

I do not know SQL very well but from my understanding I have to write something like

```
SELECT survival, gender
FROM   etitanic
```

I am not sure how to achieve this in R, any suggestions would be helpful.
I tried the following:

```
df = sqldf('select count(*) total from etitanic where survived group by sex')
df2 = t(df)
colnames(df2)=c('Female','Male')
```

which gave me this:

```
      Female Male
total    292  135
```

But I believe I need the percentages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is SQL returning fractions a requirement? Why not simply let SQL return counts and then calculate fractions in R:

```
df <- sqldf('select count(*) Total from etitanic where survived group by sex');
df / sum(df);
#      Total
#1 0.6838407
#2 0.3161593
```

Comment: But isn't that different from what we got on the previous question?

Comment: female 0.2791587
  male   0.1290631

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Yes they're different. These are the fractions of male/female survived to total survived, not of male/female survived to total (as in the previous question).

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not let you compute percentages directly. What you need to do is to compute number of survived people and total people, and then divide the two. The query looks like this:

```
select
    sex 
  , sum(case when survived then 1 else 0 end) / count(1) as survival_pct
from etitanic
group by sex
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `avg` like this:

```
sqldf('select sex, 100 * avg(survived) [%Survived] from etitanic group by sex')
```

giving:

```
     sex %Survived
1 female  75.25773
2   male  20.51672
```

To double check these numbers note from `with(etitanic, table(sex, survived))` that 292 females survived and 96 did not so the survival rate is 100 * 292 / (292 + 96) = 75.25773% and similarly for males we get 100 * 135 / (135 + 523) = 20.51672%.

Comment: When I used this command though I get different percentages: prop.table(table(etitanic$sex, etitanic$survived))

Comment: female 0.2791587
                                                                                                                        male   0.1290631

Comment: Your `prop.table` command is calculating (# female survivors) / (#males + #females) but you want (#female survivors) / #females (and similarly for males).